# WIFI slow on macbook air, not on macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

The wifi is very slow on my macbook air and iphone, my partner has no problems at all at his macbook pro.
We have two channels we can connect to (4G&5G)
I've read the other Q+A's on this forum about the topic, but I didn't find out what the issue is. It looks like my MCS, Tx and RSSI are pretty slow. Could someone help me with this issue?

Thanks very much!

[image]
[image]

Comment: For WiFi, it’s either 2.4Ghz or 5GHz.  4G and 5G are *cellular* technologies.  The 4G that you’re seeing is the cellular network of the iPhone, iPad, or whatever *hotspot* you’re connected to.  Your RSSI is fine.  The question is, are you attempting to browse the internet on that *same* iPhone hotspot?  What network is your partner’s MBP connected to?

Comment: Hi Allan thanks for your reply. These are the wifi networks me and my partner connect to from the modem. The provider is called tele2 and these are the two networks. My partner has on this netwerk no issues with watching youtube or netflix, I can't because it's too slow.